# Create a branch from an unmerged (and unckecked) pull request from github

Tags: git, github

I cloned a project from github with

```
git clone https://github.com/somecompany/someproject.git
```

Now I want to make a branch using an unmerged (on github) and unchecked pull request

```
https://github.com/somecompany/someproject/pull/1234
```

Can I do this using only git console tool?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "git console tool".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The pull request is a request to merge one branch (let's call it `branch-to-merge`) into another branch. You just have to

`git fetch`

in your local clone to fetch all  remote changes, including information about the remote `branch-to-merge`. Now, you can just

`checkout branch-to-merge`,

to check out a local copy of `branch-to-merge`. From there, you can create branches (`git checkout -b new-branch`) to work on top of those changes.

---

Edit: You should be aware of @miqdadamirali s comment:

> [...] if you commit & push anything on `branch-to-merge`, it'll be part of the PR while it's still open

So you should create a new branch instead of working directly on `branch-to-merge`.

Comment: Just a note, if you commit & push anything on `branch-to-merge`, it'll be part of the PR while it's still open